# Setting up a secondary, fully synced backup server Windows Server 2012 R2, how?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2

we're looking for a solution to set up a secondary and a fully synced backup server which would go on in case the primary server dies.

Basically...
Both server would be running 24/7, but if the primary server would die for some reason, then all the clients would get redirected to the secondary server, which would contain exactly the same data as the primary one. But we're not looking for a solution with shared storage, but more likely something which would be syncing in realtime from the primary server to the secondary server.

I only know a solution to do this for webservers.
- 3 servers, while one of them is a primary server and the second one is a secondary server and the third one redirects clients to one of the servers. For example: You're a client and you're trying to request a website, so you send the request to the third server which detects whether the primary server is running or not, in case it's not running it gets you to the secondary server, which contains exactly the same content as the primary one as its syncing in realtime (mirroring).
But how do I make this for whole servers? I would need to export everything inside the OS from the primary server to the secondary server.
Mysql, economy software database, webserver and everything running on the primary server.

Do you know any good solution for this?
Both servers are running on Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: You haven't said what, exactly, this server does. Is it a SQL server, Exchange server, File server, Print server, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving this (without a shared storage and physical system) is only possible on application level.

You need to configure all your application in a cluster mode or replicate it.

- For windows shares you could use a DFS.
- MySQL can be run using replication mode with a master and slave.
- ...